# UIViewController controller not recognizing delegate

Tags: ios, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

my first time creating a UIControlerView and it seems that the delegates are never activated. Please tell me where I am going wrong.

Thank you!
By the way I created the IBOutlet by dragging from the storyboard...

.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface CollectionController : UIViewController<UICollectionViewDelegate,UICollectionViewDataSource>

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UICollectionView *controllerTableView;

@end
```

.m

```
#import "CollectionController.h"
#import "CollectionVIewCell.h"

@interface CollectionController ()

@end

@implementation CollectionController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [[self controllerTableView]setDelegate:self];
    [[self controllerTableView]setDataSource:self];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}
-(NSInteger)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section{
    return 10;
}

-(NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInCollectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView{
    return 1;
}


-(UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

    static NSString *cellIdentifier=@"Cell";
    CollectionVIewCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

    cell.labelDisplay.text=@"hi";
    //set up data in images

    return cell;
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@end
```

Comment: What do you mean by never activated ? Are you seeing your 10 items but without the "hi" text or there are not even a cell ?

Comment: never goes into those methods, I put breakpoints in each one and never got activated

Comment: Are you sure that you've linked your XIB or Storyboard controller to the `CollectionController`? (Identity Inspector tab from Interface Builder)

Comment: yes  control drag to .h (then you see the IBOUTLET appear in the code)

Comment: No I mean : In storyboard, click on your CollectionView controller in the left pane. Then, on the right pane, go to the third tab (Identity Inspector) and check that the field "custom class" is `CollectionController` and not `UICollectionViewController`

Comment: ok, this is a view controller that I added a collection view though

Comment: ok but the goal is the same. Did your custom class is `CollectionController`(this is your custom class that you created, that handle delegates method) instead of 'UIViewController`so ?

Comment: I found the error, I was pushing it wrong (hence the black screen).  Thank you all for the comments

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try hooking up your `UICollectionView`'s delegate and data source in the xib rather than in code.

Comment: how do I connect it in IB?  where do I drag it to?

Answer (score 1):

Is it possible that your controllerTableView is getting deallocated due to the "weak" attribute?  Try using "strong" and see if that helps.

Comment: didn't help :( anything else?

Answer (score 0):

I was doing the push here wrong, it should be

```
CollectionController *controller = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"CollectionController"];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:controller animated:YES];
```

Answer (score 0):

check this inherit module is selected or not 
[image]